# Cannot run program "curl.exe": error=2, No such file or directory

Tags: kotlin, curl

I ran my code on Windows 10.
I have this code (with normal API)

```
val command =
            "curl -H X-CMC_PRO_API_KEY: ********-****-****-****-************ -H Accept: application/json -d start=1&limit=10&convert=USD -G https://pro-api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/cryptocurrency/listings/latest"
        val processBuilder = ProcessBuilder(*command.split(" ").toTypedArray())


//        processBuilder.directory(File("D:\\Program Files\\curl-7.77.0-win64-mingw\\bin"))
//        processBuilder.directory(File("C:\\Windows\\System32"))
        val process = processBuilder.start()

        val inputStream: InputStream = process.inputStream

        val exitCode = process.exitValue()

        process.destroy()
```

After run I receive this error: *Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "curl": error=2, No such file or directory*

- I have PATH to curl.exe in Environment variables (for one, that already was on drive C, and for another, that I have download on drive D)
- I tried to add "*processBuilder.directory*" for this two paths (this is comment now)
- I check paths for curls in cmd "*where curl*". It is good too
- I tried to add "*curl.exe*" at the beginning of the command
- curl command in cmd works fine

And nothing helped me. What should I do to solve this problem?

The whole error, if someone want

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.lsm.cryptotracking2, PID: 559
    java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:602)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947) 
     Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "curl": error=2, No such file or directory
        at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1050)
        at com.lsm.cryptotracking2.MainActivity.loadFrist10Coin(MainActivity.kt:106)
        at com.lsm.cryptotracking2.MainActivity.access$loadFrist10Coin(MainActivity.kt:20)
        at com.lsm.cryptotracking2.MainActivity$onCreate$1.run(MainActivity.kt:135)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947) 
     Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
        at java.lang.UNIXProcess.forkAndExec(Native Method)
        at java.lang.UNIXProcess.<init>(UNIXProcess.java:133)
        at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:141)
        at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1029)
        at com.lsm.cryptotracking2.MainActivity.loadFrist10Coin(MainActivity.kt:106) 
        at com.lsm.cryptotracking2.MainActivity.access$loadFrist10Coin(MainActivity.kt:20) 
        at com.lsm.cryptotracking2.MainActivity$onCreate$1.run(MainActivity.kt:135) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
```

Comment: Try to provide a full path to `curl`. I don't know Windows, but I believe `PATH` is really a feature of the shell, not the operating system itself, so depending on the case, `PATH` may be totally ignored when searching for a command to run.

Comment: “I have PATH to curl.exe in Environment variables” — Was it set in the process you ran your Kotlin program from?  Depending on your OS and on how you launched your program, it might get only the basic system PATH.

Comment: @gidds, i'am not sure I understand your question.  If you mean how PATH is set, path to one is in System variables in "Path" variable, and another in User variables in same variable.
Also I tried to use processBuilder.directory() to set path in the program

Comment: @broot, sorry, but can you write how exactly should I do this?

Comment: I meant something like: `val command = "C:\\somedir\\curl.exe ..."`, but nevermind, it seems Java resolves `PATH`, so it shouldn't be required to provide a full path. @gidds asked whether you set `PATH` somewhere in OS settings or generally before launching your Kotlin application or do you set it directly in your Kotlin code.